# File name with space in do set command

Tags: windows, batch-file

Apologies as I am new and may be asking a obvious question.

```
echo @off

echo starting load of West One Data Extract v1g

FOR /F %%I IN ('DIR \\<server name>\Data\Servicing\Data\abc*.* /B /O:D') DO SET NEWEST_FILE_1=%%I

echo Uploading "%NEWEST_FILE_1%"
```

As file name is "abc 123.xls" output echo is "uploading abc"

If I run `DIR \\<server name>\Data\Servicing\Data\abc*.* /B /O:D` it works fine and results in "abc 123.xls"

Can you please help as to how to change the code to accept space in file names.

Comment: `FOR /F "delims="  %%I IN ('DIR \\<server name>\Data\Servicing\Data\abc*.* /B /O:D') DO SET "NEWEST_FILE_1=%%I"`

Comment: @Squashman - why you are posting so many ansers ,as comments instead ...as ansers? Don't you want upvotes and points?

Comment: @npocmaka, because I am lazy.

Comment: @Squashman - https://weblog.masukomi.org/2014/10/03/the-five-virtues-of-a-great-programmer/  :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default the `FOR /F` command will parse the output of a command and split it up into tokens based on the default delimiters. This is all explained in the help file for the `FOR` command.  So you need to use the `DELIMS` option to tell it not to use any delimiters.

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%I IN ('DIR \\<server name>\Data\Servicing\Data\abc*.* /B /O:D') DO SET "NEWEST_FILE_1=%%I"
```